# How to do geo spatial query using scala slick

Tags: scala, geospatial, slick, spatial, spatial-query

Need to do spatial search such as finding db rows that contains location closer to user's. For example, if db contains shops with addresses, I would need the query sorted by distance from the current user (say for example using zip code)..

Comment: are you using postgresql as your database with Slick?

Comment: no, using mysql

Comment: were you able to solve this?